# compile c file to .SO with android NDK

Tags: android

I have hello world example of c file.I need to get a so file from it. But NDK generates .out file rather then a so file.

the command I use is:

```
./aarch64-linux-android21-clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 hello.c
```

outputs

```
a.out
```

Comment: so stands for shared object and it is a format used for dynamically loaded libraries. If you normally compile a C program, you will get an executable (by default called a.out, but you can change the name using a flag, if you need). Are you sure you want to produce a library instead of a program?

Comment: yes i need library,  how can i do that

Comment: sudo ./aarch64-linux-android21-clang -shared -o libdyn.so -Xlinker -soname=libdyn.so hello.c